# Audio resource file won't play from MediaElement

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a MediaElement playing(trying to play) a sound clip from within a storyboard.  When I use an absolute path to the sound file (i.e c:\file\location\alarm.wave), it works fine.  However, if I use a relative uri, it no workie.

I have my alarm.wav in a folder named Resources, that's in my project root.  I've tried setting the alarm.wav Build Action to Content, Resource, and Embedded Resource.  I've also added it in my Resources.resx.  I've tried a number of relative URI's, such as /Resources/alarm.wav and Resources/alarm.wav and pack://application:,,,/Capricorn2;component/Resources/alarm.wav.

None of those combinations work...so I must be missing something obvious here...any thoughts?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition  Binding="{Binding IsAlarming}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsAudioAlarm}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="soundPlayer">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <MediaTimeline Source="/Capricorn2;component/Resources/alarm.wav" Storyboard.TargetName="alarmSound" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="soundPlayer"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <Border >
            <Grid >
                <MediaElement x:Name="alarmSound"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Ok, so I have a combination working now.  I have the alarm.wav added to my resources.resx, the build action of the alarm.wav file is Content and Copy to Output is Copy Always, and I'm using Source="Resources/alarm.wav" and it's working.  My question still remains though, why won't the uri I have in the xaml code work??

Answer (score 1):

A relative URI wouldn't have '/' in front of it. So if your sound file's absolute path is

> /ProjectName/Resources/alarm.wav

its relative path is then

> Resources/alarm.wav